# SQL Server 2008 Is it Possible to Have Select Top Return Nulls

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
(Select top 1 pvd.Code from PatientVisitDiags pvd
    where pvd.PatientVisitId = pv.PatientVisitId
    Order By pvd.Listorder) as "DX1",
(Select top 1 a.code from (Select top 2 pvd.Code,pvd.ListOrder from PatientVisitDiags pvd
    where pvd.PatientVisitId = pv.PatientVisitId
    Order By pvd.Listorder)a order by a.ListOrder DESC ) as "DX2",
(Select top 1 a.code from (Select top 3 pvd.Code,pvd.ListOrder from PatientVisitDiags pvd
    where pvd.PatientVisitId = pv.PatientVisitId
    Order By pvd.Listorder)a order by a.ListOrder DESC ) as "DX3",
(Select top 1 a.code from (Select top 4 pvd.Code,pvd.ListOrder from PatientVisitDiags pvd
    where pvd.PatientVisitId = pv.PatientVisitId
    Order By pvd.Listorder)a order by a.ListOrder DESC ) as "DX4",
(Select top 1 a.code from (Select top 5 pvd.Code,pvd.ListOrder from PatientVisitDiags pvd
    where pvd.PatientVisitId = pv.PatientVisitId
    Order By pvd.Listorder)a order by a.ListOrder DESC ) as "DX5"
```

The above code is what I am using currently (It is not optimal but is only being used once for a one time Data Export).

In the database that we are currently exporting from, there is a table PatientVisitDiags that has columns "ListOrder" and "Code". There can be between 1 and 5 codes. The ListOrder holds the number of that code. For example:

```
ListOrder|Code   |
1        |M51.27 |
2        |M54.17 |
3        |G83.4  |
```

I am trying to export the Code to its corresponding Column in the new table(DX1,DX2..etc). If I sort by ListOrder I can get them in the order I need (Row 1 to DX1 | Row 2 to DX2 etc.) However when I run the above SQL code, If the source table only has 3 Codes DX4 and DX5 will repeat DX3. For Example:

```
DX1    |DX2    |DX3   |DX4   |DX5
M51.27 |M54.17 |G83.4 |G83.4 |G83.4
```

Is there a way to have TOP return NULL values if you Select TOP more than what is given? SQL Sever 2008 does not allow for OFFSET/FETCH, this is what I normally would have done given the option to select individual rows.

TL:DR

```
ID | Name

 1 | Joe

 2 | Eric

 3 | Steve

 4 | John
```

If I have a table like above and run

```
SELECT TOP 5 Name FROM Table
```

Is there anyway to return?

```
Joe

Eric

Steve

John

NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're really doing is pivoting. So pivot! Try this little query:

```
WITH Top5 AS (
   SELECT TOP 5
      Dx = 'DX' + Convert(varchar(11), Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY pvd.Listorder)),
      pvd.Code
   FROM dbo.PatientVisitDiags pvd
   WHERE pvd.PatientVisitId = @patientVisitId
)
SELECT *
FROM
   Top5 t
   PIVOT (Max(Code) FOR Dx IN (DX1, DX2, DX3, DX4, DX5)) p
;
```

To answer your second question about getting an unpivoted rowset, basically do the same thing but provide the 5 rows somehow and left join to the desired data.

```
WITH Data AS (
   SELECT TOP 5
      Seq = Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY ID),
      Name
   FROM dbo.Table
   ORDER BY ID
)
SELECT
   n.Seq,
   t.Name
FROM
   (VALUES
      (1), (2), (3), (4), (5) -- or a numbers-generating CTE perhaps
   ) n (Seq)
   LEFT JOIN Top 5 t
      ON n.Seq = t.Seq
;
```

**Side note**

The fact that you're doing this:

```
where pvd.PatientVisitId = pv.PatientVisitId
```

tells me you're not using ANSI joins. Stop. Don't do that any more. Put this join condition in the `ON` clause of a `JOIN`. It's the year 2016... why are you using join syntax from the last century?

Oh, and prefix the schema on the table names. Look it up--you'll find actual performance reasons why you should do that. It's not just about the time taken to find the correct schema, but also about the execution plan cache...

Answer (score 0):

one at a time - answering the last question

create a table with a bunch of null

```
select top (5) col
from 
(
select col from table1 
union 
select nulCol from nullTable
) tt 
order by tt.col
```